# How to define "if and only if" rule in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, gurobi

Now I have two binary decision variables X1 and X2. If I intend to define a constraint that X2 could be 1 if and only if X1 is 1. In other word, X2 is a sequel to X1. How could I define this kind of logic in linear programming?

Any hint will be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your question.

```
x1 = 1 <=> x2 = 1
```

is the same as

```
x1=x2
```

I think you want

```
x1 = 1 => x2 = 1
```

i.e. no "if and only if" but only "if". This can be written as:

```
x2 >= x1
```

The reverse

```
x1=0 => x2=0
```

is of course just as trivial:

```
x2 <= x1
```

Also note that LPs don't have binary variables (LP refers to continuous variables). Binary variables can be used only in (mixed) integer programs.

Comment: Thanks first. Your are right, it is a integer linear programming. Maybe I did not express this problem in right way. The expression should be `if x1=1 then (x2=0 or x2=1)`. But `if x1=0 then x2=0)`.

Comment: ...................x2 <= x1

Comment: Finally, I got it! Thank you again.